# Parsing unsigned ints (uint32_t) in python's C api

Tags: python, c, python-2.x, cpython

If I write a function accepting a single unsigned integer (`0` - `0xFFFFFFFF`), I can use:

```
uint32_t myInt;
if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "I", &myInt))
    return NULL;
```

And then from python, I can pass an `int` or `long`.

But what if I get passed a list of integers?

```
uint32_t* myInts;
PyObject* pyMyInts;
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &pyMyInts);

if (PyList_Check(intsObj)) {
    size_t n = PyList_Size(v);
    myInts = calloc(n, sizeof(*myInts));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        PyObject* item = PyList_GetItem(pyMyInts, i);

        // What function do I want here?
        if(!GetAUInt(item, &myInts[i]))
            return NULL;
    }
}

// cleanup calloc'd array on exit, etc
```

Specifically, my issue is with dealing with:

- Lists containing a mixture of `int`s and `long`s
- detecting overflow when assigning to the the uint32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a tuple and use the same method you used for a single argument. On the C side, the tuple objects are not really immutable, so it wouldn't be to much trouble.

Also [`PyLong_AsUnsignedLong`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsUnsignedLong) could work for you. It accepts int and long objects and raises an error otherwise. But if `sizeof(long)` is bigger than 4, you might need to check for an upper-bound overflow yourself.

```
static int 
GetAUInt(PyObject *pylong, uint32_t *myint) {
    static unsigned long MAX = 0xffffffff;
    unsigned long l = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(pylong);

    if (l == -1 && PyErr_Occurred() || l > MAX) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError, "can't convert to uint32_t");
        return false;
    }

    *myint = (uint32_t) l;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway way to return false and clear the error? (I need to check the argument for multiple types)

Comment: @Eric Just call `PyErr_Clear()`. Just put it this way, since you're returning `NULL` in your code.